# Scala allocate sequential index array

Tags: arrays, scala, dynamically-generated

In scala I would like to dynamically allocate an array of sequential index values.

In R it is simply `maxindex = 10` then `array = 1:maxindex` which returns `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

Is it possible to do this in scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try [Range](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.2/scala/Range.html) method:

```
Range(val start : Int, val end : Int, val step : Int)
```

You could use it like this:

```
var yourArray = range(1, 10, 1)
```

That will return an array like you want: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

Or even more simple:

```
var yourArraySimpler = 1 until 11
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.2/scala/Range.html). From the link:

> The Range class represents integer values in range [start;end) with
>   non-zero step value step. Sort of acts like a sequence also (supports
>   length and contains).

Comment: `1 until 10` will return `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`, not including `10`. You need `1 to 10` to include both numbers

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as:

```
val arr = 1 to 10
```

which uses an [implicit conversion](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef$@intWrapper(x:Int):scala.runtime.RichInt) to generate a `Range` as described in @cacho's answer. `Range` is a subclass of `Seq`, but you can call `.toArray` on it if you specifically need an array.